# Wifi hotspot switching on/off

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, hotspot, wireless-hotspot

I activated a hotspot wifi on mobile phone (tested both with Iphone 8 and Google Pixel, different sim card). The hotspot switch on-off about every 1 second. Clients can't keep stable connection (tested with both linux and windows).

How can i deepen the situation, to understand what is the root cause of this behavior?

Note: The connection and data traffic sometimes properly work for some minutes. This make me excluding that the carrier is limiting hotspotting.

Comment: It could be that your carrier prevents hotspotting, to limit your data usage.

Comment: The carrier can block data transfer, but cannot do anything to the local Wi-Fi network itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the same setup in other places, and the issue never happened. When come back to the first place, the issue happened again. So it follow it's a matter of electromagnetic pollution.